# How to use a PHP variable in Inner Join MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, join

I have been trying for the past day to get mysql to recognize my PhP variable, but I have had no luck so far.

The code:

```
...connect to db...
session_start();
//Calls up Session stored variable
$currentUsr= $_SESSION['username'];
//SQL Query
$sql= 'SELECT Users.Username, books.* FROM Users
       INNER JOIN UserLinkBooks lb
       ON Users.Username = lb.Username
       INNER JOIN Books
       ON lb.bkTitle = books.Title
       WHERE Users.Username = "$currentUsr"';
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);                                                                
//Error Check
if (!$result) {                                                                                   
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn)); 
   exit();}
//display row
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                                                                                                        
    echo "<strong>".$row['Title']."</strong>".$row['Description']."</br>";}
```

My issue is that the $currentUsr is not properly calling the username that was passed. After doing an error check on it, it seems to be empty.

What I do not understand is that when I use the code :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `Username`='$currentUsr'";
```

The variable is processed and works fine, calling up the book title's and description perfectly. Also, if I manually type in:
      WHERE Users.UserName = "Bill"';
It works fine.

Some of the other errors I've gotten from various attempts are:

```
  WHERE Users.UserName = '.'$currentUsr';
  Error: Unknown column '$currentUsr' in 'where clause'
```

or

```
  WHERE Users.UserName = '.$currentUsr;  
  Error:  Unknown column 'Bill' in 'where clause'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: PHP strings behave differently depending on whether they're double or single quoted.

Comment: Just sure that your user isn't Bobby Tables (http://xkcd.com/327/). Any user supplied input should be wrapped in the `mysql_real_escape_string`, or better yet: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Some friendly advice would be to look up the user information using the User.id instead of the User.UserName. This is part of a larger concept known as 'data normalization' and learning it will save you may hairs because in a UTF-8 character set, 'Bill' and 'Bïll' and 'Bîll' would accidentally end up being the same user, but foreign keys 1001, 1802, and 2242 are clearly different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is in a single quoted string, preventing interpolation. You can try:

```
$sql = "SELECT Users.Username, books.* FROM Users
        INNER JOIN UserLinkBooks lb
        ON Users.Username = lb.Username
        INNER JOIN Books
        ON lb.bkTitle = books.Title
        WHERE Users.Username = '" . $currentUsr ."'";
```

Using concatenation makes the code more readable in my opinion. Having said that, you should look into using parameterized queries as they cut down on injection issues. Mysqli has such capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using variables inside strings, you should put these strings within double, not single quotes, otherwise the variables are not replaced with their values.

Also check this question: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you use double quotes, then put your variables in curly braces - else use Concatinatoin with the dot.